# How to use SPDY with HttpClient 4?

Tags: java, android, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, spdy

How to use SPDY with HttpClient 4? Is it possible? If yes, can you give an example? I don't want to use other libraries, but if it is not possible, what is the best way to use SPDY?

Comment: "I don't want to use other libraries" -- Google abandoned support for HttpClient a couple of years ago and has been steering developers to use anything else. Google themselves are using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) for the HTTP/SPDY stack in Android 4.4+, and it offers an optional `HttpClient`-compatible API layer. Talented developers would "use other libraries".

Comment: @CommonsWare but I'm using HttpClient 4.3.5, released in 30/07/2014...

Comment: I'll take your word for that -- I am not aware of an Android-friendly packaging of HttpClient that moves it into a separate package, to not conflict with the built-in HttpClient implementation. I am not aware of SPDY support with HttpClient (other than the OkHttp compatibility layer that I mentioned), though I haven't gone looking for SPDY for HttpClient either.

Comment: @CommonsWare http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Apache HttpClient is very unlikely to ever support SPDY. It will support HTTP/2.0 though.